# How to config git to display moved lines when using git add -p?

Tags: git, git-config

I often use `git add -p` to commit parts of a file. I also have this setting in my .gitconfig:

```
[diff]
    renames = copies
    colormoved = zebra
[color "diff"]
    oldMoved = magenta italic
    newMoved = magenta italic dim
```

So it applies fine to `git diff` but what about the diff shown when doing `git add -p`? I can't see the moved lines and I don't find how to configure this on google.